# getting all the possible permutation of cards between several players

Tags: algorithm, playing-cards

I am trying to get all the possible deals of `n` cards between 3 players, where each player `i` need exactly `n_i` cards and some of the players can not get some of the cards.

For example, assume there are 4 cards: `Ac,Jh,9d,2s` and player `N,E,S` needs `1,1,2` cards respectively, but `N` can't get the `Ac`, and `S` can't get the `Jh`.

The input is the list of `n` cards, and the restrictions for each position and for each card:

```
List<Card> unplayedCards
Map<Position, Integer> numberOfCardsEachPlayerNeeds
Map<Card, List<Position>> possiblePositionsForCard
```

The output should be a list of the possible deals so

```
List<Map<Position, List<Card>>>
```

I am writing in Java, but it is not important which language the answer is.

Comment: Is there a predetermined list of what cards the players cannot get?

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easiest to do this with a recursive algorithm. Python-like pseudocode:

```
function possible_deals(players, cards):
  output := []
  generate_deals(players, cards, 0, {}, output)
  return output

function generate_deals(players, cards, index, assignment, output):
  if index >= len(cards):
    output.append(assignment)
  else:
    card := cards[index]
    for player in players:
      if player doesn't have enough cards yet and player can have card:
        assignment[card] = player
        generate_deals(players, cards, index + 1, assignment, output)
        del assignment[card]
```

We're assuming pass-by-reference semantics for `assignment` and `output` so that recursive function calls can modify these.

Each entry in the `output` list contains a map from cards to players. From this, it's easy to reconstruct the hands.

Answer (score 0):

Made a Java version based on @Thomas answer.

```
static List<Map<Position, CardsList>> getAllPossibleDeals(CardsList cards, Map<Position, Integer> cardsPerPosition,
                                                          Map<Card, List<Position>> positionsPerCard, List<Card> unplayedCardsOrderedByPossibilities) {

    List<Map<Position, CardsList>> possibleDeals = new ArrayList(); // all the deals
    Map<Position, CardsList> assignment = new HashMap<>(); // a single deal.
    generateDeals(cards, cardsPerPosition, positionsPerCard, possibleDeals, 0, assignment); 
    return possibleDeals;
}


private static void generateDeals(CardsList cards, Map<Position, Integer> cardsPerPosition, Map<Card, List<Position>> positionsPerCard,
                                  List<Map<Position, CardsList>> possibleDeals, int i, Map<Position, CardsList> assignment) {

    if (i >= cards.size()){
        Map<Position, CardsList> assignmentCopy = deepCopyMap(assignment);
        possibleDeals.add(assignmentCopy);
    }
    else {
        Card card = cards.get(i);
        for (Position pos : positionsPerCard.get(card)) {
            if (assignment.get(pos) == null || cardsPerPosition.get(pos) > assignment.get(pos).size()){
                // position can have the card
                assignment.computeIfAbsent(pos, k -> new CardsList()).add(card);
                generateDeals(cards, cardsPerPosition, positionsPerCard, possibleDeals, i+1, assignment);
                assignment.get(pos).remove(card);
            }
        }
    }
}
```